# Помогите улучшить цикл

Tags: python, циклы

Я создаю запрос на создание таблицы  для базы данных SQL в питоне. Но максимально я могу создать только 26 столбцов с названием A-Z. Как создавать больше столбцов типа АА - и так до бесконечности(Как в таблицах Excel)

```
request = "CREATE TABLE Extable (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY"

for i in range(0, col_quantity):
    if i <= 25:
        columm = ", %s VARCHAR(255)" % chr(65 + i)
        request = request + columm
request = request + ")"
```

Comment: я уверен, что человек, который написал код из вопроса, может решить и проблему, в этом вопросе озвученную.

Comment: делите номер на 26, остаток прибавляйте к A и собирайте в строку. Так вы по номеру получите название

Comment: а что вы подразумеваете под номером ? @splash58

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эта функция возвращает имя колонки по ее последовательному номеру

Имейте в виду, что счет колонок идет от единицы. Впрочем, если нужно от 0, просто добавьте единичку при входе в  функцию

```
def colname(num):
    name = []
    while num :
        num, rest = divmod(num-1, ord('Z')-ord('A')+1)
        name.append(chr(rest+ord('A')))
    return ''.join(name[::-1])


print(colname(1))
print(colname(26))
print(colname(27))
print(colname(28))

A
Z
AA
AB
```

Comment: Все работает. Большое спасибо